# Windows 10 Upgrade Breaks access to Home Network Printers

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, network-printer

I have just upgraded from WinPro 7 to WinPro 10.   Our home network printers are connected to a WinPro 7 machine.

As soon as I upgraded I lost access to the home network printers.

I deleted them and tried to rediscover them but no joy.

I've tried reinstalling the printer drivers but no joy.

I also tried manually adding the shared printers to my machine but WinPro10 can't see them.  I also get the "operation could not be completed (error 0x0000007e) the specified module could not be found" error.

Any idea how I can handle this?

Comment: File and printer sharing is disabled by default, enable it in network and sharing center.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Moab, I found the answer.  In the conversion from WinPro 8 to WinPro 10, the homegroup was disconnected.

To fix the problem go to Control Panel > Network and Internet > HomeGroup and re-add the home group.  You will need the password for the homegroup.